# Mutli-row mutli-column matrix in overleaf

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm very new to Overleaf\LateX and coding in general - I'm struggling quite a bit with the tables.

I managed to do this table but I want to include a sort of footer in the table. Initially the table looks like this.

[image]

But when I use multi-column to add that line basically it just goes weird like this

[image]

This is what I have for now;

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{\label{messagesexp} Models and related treatment messages in the survey}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{4cm} | m{9cm}| }
\hline
\textbf{Models} & \textbf{Displayed messages}\\\hline\hline

\textbf{Model 1} &  \\\hline
Social norms & \textit{“Did you know? 46\% of young people declared they had reported illegal and hamful* posts on social media.”}\\ \hline

\textbf{Model 2} &  \\\hline
{{Anonymity and Privacy}}& \textit{“Did you know? 46\% of young people declared they had reported illegal and hamful* posts on social media.”}\\ \hline

\textbf{Model 3} &  \\\hline
{{Responsibility and change}} & \textit{“Reporting makes a difference. Your report allows to improve detection algorithms to better detect illegal and hamful* content.”}\\ \hline

\textbf{Control group} &  \\\hline
 & \textit{“Did you know? Sixdegrees.com was considered the “first” social media platfom* in history and was founded in 1997.”}\\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{| l{1em} |}{*Note: The typos included in the displayed messages are deliberate and relate to attention checks.}
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The `l` column type you use in your multicolumn does not take an argument and it does not allow line breaks. If you want line breaks, use e.g. `p{5cm}` or whatever

Comment: Please don't post just code fragment. Always make a small, but compilable test document which people can use to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{\label{messagesexp} Models and related treatment messages in the survey}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{4cm} | m{9cm}| }
\hline
\textbf{Models} & \textbf{Displayed messages}\\\hline\hline

\textbf{Model 1} &  \\\hline
Social norms & \textit{"Did you know? 46\% of young people declared they had reported illegal and hamful* posts on social media."}\\ \hline

\textbf{Model 2} &  \\\hline
{{Anonymity and Privacy}}& \textit{"Did you know? 46\% of young people declared they had reported illegal and hamful* posts on social media."}\\ \hline

\textbf{Model 3} &  \\\hline
{{Responsibility and change}} & \textit{"Reporting makes a difference. Your report allows to improve detection algorithms to better detect illegal and hamful* content."}\\ \hline

\textbf{Control group} &  \\\hline
 & \textit{"Did you know? Sixdegrees.com was considered the "first" social media platfom* in history and was founded in 1997."}\\ \hline

\multicolumn{2}{|m{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}|}{*Note: The typos included in the displayed messages are deliberate and relate to attention checks.} \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

With the following output:
[image]